# Does allowing unsafe-inline script defeat the purpose of CSP?

Tags: content-security-policy

I am reviewing the Content-Security-Policy headers set in one of our webservers and I see this is how it is set (where 'example.com' is our trusted website).

> Content-Security-Policy: "default-src 'self'; script-src 'self' data:
>   'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; img-src 'self' *.example.com; font-src
>   *; connect-src 'self' *example.com"

My questions are:

1) Won't whitelisting `unsafe-inline` and `unsafe-eval` kind of defeat the whole CSP?

2) If 'unsafe-inline' is allowed or whitelisted as above, can someone call a JavaScript from an external website, say www.xxxxxx.com that is not whitelisted in `script-src` directive and there-by defeat the whole purpose of CSP? Eg: `<script src="www.xxxxxx.com/bad.js">`

I went through [this question here](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/152547/why-are-inline-scripts-and-styles-considered-not-secure-under-content-security-p) and going by the answers, it does look like the above CSP is *not* good.

Answer (score 6):

> Won't whitelisting unsafe-inline and unsafe-eval kind of defeat the whole CSP?

Yes. A tight CSP will make it harder to exploit XSS by restricting the scripts that can be executed. Using unsafe-inline and unsafe-eval allow to run any script. This is also why they are prefixed by `unsafe-`, to discourage you from using them in the CSP.

Of course the data: protocol also makes it possible to bypass the CSP, since you can encode any script as data: URL.

> If 'unsafe-inline' is allowed or whitelisted as above, can someone call a JavaScript from an external website

You could retrieve the script contents and run them from within JavaScript. Including it with `<script src="www.xxxxxx.com/bad.js">` doesn't work but since you can run JavaScript anyway there are other ways to run external script.

Comment: Thank you. So, this CSP does prevent calling JavaScripts from external websites, that way it does help in making the webpage more secure that not having this CSP?

Comment: If you have your front door wide open, does locking your back door make things "more secure"?

Answer (score 0):

Sjoerd covered what are (in my opinion) the major points on this topic, but I’d like to add that allowing inline JavaScript doesn’t fully make CSP worthless here. There is still a point to using a well-written Content Security Policy outside the boundaries of avoiding XSS.

As we’re all aware, CSP is a deeply powerful tool. While the bulk of its power dwells in making it easier to defend against XSS and its friends, it also has a number of functionalities that remain valuable even once you disable the XSS-specific features and open up that vector. These include:

- Features tangential to preventing XSS, like the `sandbox` directive
- Independent features, like the `upgrade-insecure-requests` directive
- Supporting features that can be deeply leveraged on their own, like
  the reporting capabilities

In case it’s useful, Mozilla has an excellent write-up of CSP’s features [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy).